# SQL Select All Record In Each Group (Name, DOB)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with `ID` `DOB` `AMOUNT` `RECEIVER_NAME` `SENDER_NAME` `SETTLE_FEE` columns.

Sample Data

```
ID  DOB         AMOUNT  RECEIVER_NAME   SENDER_NAME     SETTLE_FEE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   10-06-1990  100       Jose      Benn        12
2   12-06-1990  200       Jim       Mike        12
3   10-06-1990  300       Kate      Benn        12
4   12-06-1990  100       Amy       Mike        12
5   10-06-1990  200       Alison    Benn        12
6   12-06-1990  300       Mary      Mike        12
```

Expected result

```
ID  DOB         SENDER_NAME
---------------------------
1   10-06-1990  Benn    
        |--------AMOUNT  RECEIVER_NAME  SETTLE_FEE
                  100      Jose            12
                  300      Kate            12
                  200      Alison          12
2   12-06-1990  Mike    
        |--------AMOUNT  RECEIVER_NAME  SETTLE_FEE
                  200      Jim             12
                  100      Amy             12
                  300      Mary            12
```

I need to get all the data of each sender name.

I tried using group_concat(), But, it can take only 1024 characters.

So, what is the efficient way to achieve this scenario.

I can't use PL/SQL and no session related values allowed.

I need all the receiver's name, amount, fee for all the sender_name. What is the efficient way to do it.

Thanks,
Jose

Comment: Show sample data, query your attempted, and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution:

Just use an ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ID, DOB,SENDER, AMOUNT,  RECEIVER_NAME,  SETTLE_FEE
FROM inputTable
ORDER BY SENDER,DOB;
```

In displaying as you want the data, you just use code like (dummy code, javscriptish):

```
var previousSender="";
while(var row=db.fetch()) {
  if(row.sender!=previousSender) {
    console.log(id+" "+row.dob+" "+row.sender);
    previousSend=row.sender();
  } else {
    console.log("        |-------"+row.amount+" "+row.receiver_name+" "+row.settle_fee);
  }
}
```

As you can see: id is random since it has no relation to the dob or sender in your model. It is just a row counter.